# How would you cut out these table legs?

Tags: mesh, objects

Sorry if this is a dumb question to ask, I did try to search on here and on google to get my answer but I could only find cutting out circles, mostly. I did watch some youtube vids on cutting out holes but I'm stuck with how to work w/the legs in the middle. I'm trying to create this table from scratch and I'm not sure how I would go about to cutting my mesh to get the legs like this? Once the cut outs are done how can I then create the criss-cross legs? Extruding from sides loop cuts I've done and mirroring?

[image]

Again apologies if this can easily be done, I'm still new to blender so I'm feeling kind of stuck w/this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hello :). There are no dumb questions. I'm sure someone will help out. Mirroring surely sounds like a good idea :).

Comment: @JachymMichal thank you for nice words! Hopefully someone will be able to help me with this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's symmetrical, you can use Mirror Modifier.

1. Create bottom right part of the X stretcher (I used *Knife project tool* to cut the end part)
2. Position origin to the center of the table
3. Use mirror modifier on X and Z axis

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped me see what I can do :)

Comment: Glad to be of help :).